# what he thinks is directly on his mouth

Tags: verbs

What is the term used for a person who says something without processing the suitability/appropriateness of that thing according to the situation.I mean what he thinks is directly on his mouth ...

Comment: "Put mouth in motion before putting brain in gear" is a common informal expression in the US.

Answer (score 3):

Having a word "directly on one's mouth" isn't really an English idiom.

We do say "speaking without thinking"; we speak of a need to "engage one's brain before one's mouth"; and there is the verb *blurt,* which is quite expressive.

> [with object] Say (something) suddenly and without careful consideration:
>   *she blurted out the truth*
>
> [with direct speech]: ‘It wasn’t my idea,’ Gordon blurted
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blurt)

A related expression is "opening one's mouth only [to put one's foot in it](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/put-one%27s-foot-in-it-or-put-one%27s-foot-in-one%27s-mouth?q=put+one%27s+foot+in+it)" or "foot-in-mouth syndrome". That phrase ultimately derives from stepping forward fearlessly and promptly tread in something rather nasty.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that he **has no filter** (as in, there's no filter between his brain and his mouth).

Comment: Damn, I was going to suggest this! Why not give examples of it used in the wild? Or include a dictionary reference.

Answer (score 0):

To speak *unguardedly*, *unthinkingly*. Idioms include:

**off the top of one's head** (can have this meaning):

> *(right) off the top of one's head*
>
> Fig. **without giving it too much thought** or without precise
>   knowledge.

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+top+of+head) [bolding mine]

............................

> **Shooting from the hip.**
>
> *shoot from the hip*
>
> Speak or act recklessly or impulsively, as in *Steve isn't very
>   tactful; indeed, he's known for shooting from the hip.*

[AHD of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+from+the+hip)